# Input button different outputs

Tags: html, forms, input

There are 2 different types I have used:

```
1. <input type=submit>
2. <input type=image>
```

Option 1 works perfeclty but its impossible to add a picture like option 2.

Option 2 works but when I want to get the $_POST['Submit'] value then it does not work for this option only for option 1.

What can I do to have the same function as option 1 but still have an image like option 2?

Comment: is it important that you get the $_POST['Submit'] value?

Comment: yes because Im checking if the form is created so it can recall any errors such as not filled inputs since I dont want to use "required" as people can create own forms and manipulate the system

Answer (score 0):

You can use css like so:

```
<input type="submit" class="submitImage" value="">
```

and css:

```
.submitImage{
    width: 205px;
    height: 58px;
    background: url(images/submit.png); /* change it to your image */
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: for some reason, this dont work I even tried with url of different images